# Why cannot I return values from two functions in Java?

Tags: java

[Error description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6itf.png)

I can return either getMonth() or getYear() from the following code.

When both are called, an error is displayed.

I have tried giving the value of m and y separately in the calculate date function and that works perfectly !!
Any suggestions?

I am a beginner, apologies if there is a trivial mistake, though there shouldn't be according to me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Second_Java {

public static int getMonth() {

    int a;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the input for the required month: ");
    a = sc.nextInt(); // stored in 'a' locally

    while (a < 1 || a > 12) {

        a = -1;
        System.out.println(a);

    }
    sc.close();
    return a;
}

public static int getYear() {

    int b;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the input for the required year: ");
    b = input.nextInt(); // stored in 'a' locally

    while (b < 1) {

        b = -2;
        System.out.println(b);

    }
    input.close();
    return b;
}

public static void calculateDays(int m, int y) {

    switch (m) {
    case 4:
    case 6:
    case 9:
    case 11:
        m = 30;
        System.out.println(m);
        break;
    case 2:
        if (y % 400 == 0 || (y % 4 == 0 && y % 100 != 0)) {
            m = 29;
            System.out.println(m);
        } else {
            m = 28;
            System.out.println(m);
        }
        break;
    default: {
        m = 31;
        System.out.println(m);
    }

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int m = getMonth();
    int y = getYear();
    calculateDays(m, y);
}
```

}

Comment: how are you calling above methods  ?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what your question and/or problem is.

Comment: I think he means returning both values together, rather than simultaneously in the sense of threading

Comment: returning values from getMonth and getYear in the m and y variables, what part is not understandable?

Comment: A method can only return one "thing".  But that "thing" can be anything you like.  You can define a custom class which holds multiple values and return an instance of that class.

Comment: @RahulLamba: Well, what's potentially not understandable is that you're asking how to return values from `getMonth()` and `getYear()` into `m` and `y` variables, but the code *is already doing exactly that*.  Are you asking how to return two values from a single method?  Or something else?  Is the code presented here not working in some specific way?

Comment: @RahulLamba Are you asking why a method can only have one return type? Or maybe you would already be happy by knowing you don't need your local m and y variables at all and could just inline the method calls and write `calculateDays(getMonth(), getYear());`

Comment: I think i figured out what your actual problem is: Your loops are messed up beyond redemption: `while (a < 1 && a > 12)` <- How can a number be both smaller than 1 AND bigger than 12? This condition can never be fulfilled. `while (b < 1) {b = -2;System.out.println(b);}` If this loop is entered once then b will never get bigger than 1 (you set it to -2) and therefor the loop will never stop.

Comment: Who can't get redemption? Changed the condition to And ||. And the second while loop i,e, getYear is changed to if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing the Scanner also closes the input stream it's scanning -- in this case `System.in`. Hence, when you subsequently call getYear(), it finds the input stream `System.in` already closed.

One way to avoid this is to use the same Scanner in both methods, by passing it as an argument to the methods.

From the [Java API docs for Scanner.close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close--):

> `public void close()`
>
> Closes this scanner.
>
> If this scanner has not yet been closed then if its underlying readable also implements the `Closeable` interface then the readable's close method will be invoked. If this scanner is already closed then invoking this method will have no effect.

By the way, the purpose of the loops in `getMonth()` and `getYear()` are unclear. If you want to continue scanning until a valid value is entered, then you want to include a call to `Scanner.nextInt()` inside the loops. And consider using a do-while statement, since you know you want to read at least one value.

Comment: Thanks a ton!! :D 
This was the first time I used this scanner thing, I am adapted to scanf and Cin from C and ++.

Comment: @RahulLamba - You're welcome. And welcome to stackoverflow. If you consider this answer useful, you can upvote by clicking the up-triangle to the left. If you consider it the best answer, you can accept it by clicking the checkbox outline to the left.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, simply by defining an object with both values as fields e.g. for the above.

```
class MonthAndYear {
   public int month;
   public int year;
}
```

and your function can execute both your methods above, and return an instance of `MonthAndYear` populated with the month and year values.

In the above case, your month and year are obviously closely tied together, and you're on your way to (re)defining some sort of `Date` class.

Note that lots of codebases have a `Pair` object (or similar) for this sort of things. If you're using Scala, you can couple the two values together trivially using a *tuple* (e.g. like this `(month, year)` )

Comment: The idea is that if two or more common values stick together a lot, they can be bundled into a class, then instances of the class can be passed around as a single object (containing both the values).

Comment: Hi! I can surely try this but why is the above code not working?

Comment: That is a different question, and perhaps worth a post on its own

Comment: @RahulLamba: Depends on what you mean by "not working".  You'll want to describe specifically the problem you're observing.